# How do I put a search field within a form in yii?

Tags: search, yii

here is an example

Before:

> Create Pig
>
> [search chicken textfield] [search chicken button]
>
> [name text field]
>
> [another text field]
>
> [submit button]

After clicking search:

> Create Pig
>
> /List of Chickens/
>
> [name text field]
>
> [another text field]
>
> [submit button]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [search chicken textfield] [search chicken button]

Better use it:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutocomplete', array(
   'model' => $model,
   'attribute' => 'chicken',
   'minLength'=>'999', // for disable autosearching
));
CHtml::button('Search', array(
    'onclick'=>'$("#Pig_chicken").autocomplete( "search", "" );',
));
```

When user type search string it will be auto completed by ajax request (or use predefined list) for useful search

Comment: i guess that is the case for search on keyup, on submit the search it is better to have ajax call function and update the div or form where the result is to be displayed.

Comment: Well, autocomplete options allow set search via ajax by pressing `enter`. It's prefer to use already function than you will write by yourself a new bycicle

Comment: Or make 'options'=>array('minLength'=>'4',),

Comment: Thanks! It works. Only problem is, how do I get the value in the autocomplete form so I can put it in a hidden text field for submission?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I see what exactly would you like to do.

I think that you can create form as normally and update it by ajax.

1. Init form
2. on button click make ajax call
3. update form from ajax response